# Binary Tree in Javascript

Tags: javascript, data-structures, binary-tree, rhino

I'm working on this assignment: http://www.cs.colostate.edu/~anderson/ct310/index.html/doku.php?id=assignments:assignment_2

I'm building a binary tree in Javascript. Basically it's a relational tree, we have this tree class that takes 3 arguments: data,left child,right child. Left & right child are just new tree objects stored in var.

Here's the tree class:

```
function Tree( data, left, right ) 
{   
    // pravite data 
    var data = data; 
    var leftChild = left; 
    var rightChild = right; 

    // public functions 
    this.getData = function()
    {
        return data;
    }

    this.left = function()
    {
        return leftChild; 
    }

    this.right = function()
    {
        return rightChild; 
    }

}
```

Here's the toString() method

```
Tree.prototype.toString = function(indent) 
{
  var spaces = '';
  if (!indent)
  {
    indent = 0;
  }
  else{
    spaces = spaces*indent; 
  }
    // if the left tree isn't void
    if(this.tree().left())
    {
        this.tree().left().toString(indent+5); 
    }
    if(this.tree().right())
    {
        this.tree.right().toString(indent+5); 
    }
    print(spaces + this.data);
}
```

Here's the data I get passed into. We're using Rhino in the command line to test.

```
var abc = new Tree('a', new Tree('b'), new Tree('c'));
abc.toString()
```

I get a stack over flow on the toString method. My professor says to use the this.Left() in the if statement because when you recurse it will fail when it's undefined.

Any ideas what's wrong?

Comment: did you mean: if(this.left()) -- without the this.tree()? There is no this.tree in the constructor :)

Comment: It's strange to me to call this class "tree" instead of "node" as tree is the name of the larger structure. I would call a structure composed of trees with two pointers a binary forest. ba-bum-ch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, your last reference to the right branch is missing some parentheses...

```
this.tree.right().toString(indent+5) // <-- right here
```

That asid, I don't see `this.tree()` defined anywhere. I think it should be `this.left()` and `this.right()` in all those places.

Also, for a slight optimisation, consider something like:

```
var l = this.left();
if( l) l.toString(indent+5);
```

This avoids an extra function call.

Answer (score 1):

Your recursive function has no base case.  It will just keep going forever.

If your node doesn't have any children, than don't call ToString on them()